# Check if observer contains some element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

To check if array contains `undefined` I can do it like this `[undefined].indexOf(undefined)` or this `[undefined].some(el => el === undefined)`. But in my Vue.js app I've got `-1` and `false`. I tried to print my data and I've got `[__ob__: Observer]`. How to check if Observer contains undefined?

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: [undefined]
  },
  methods: {
    someFunction() {
      console.log(this.data.some(el => el === undefined), this.data.indexOf(undefined));
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue.js expects `data` to be an object, not an array.

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
     prop: [undefined]
  },
  methods: {
    someFunction() {
      console.log(this.prop.some(el => el === undefined), this.prop.indexOf(undefined));
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to solve a problem, because `prop` is `[__ob__: Observer]` and `console.log(this.prop.some(el => el === undefined), this.prop.indexOf(undefined));` is `false, -1`

Comment: @rel1x Each property into data object has the observer, that's how VueJS track the changes and make things reactive - that's normal

Comment: @BelminBedak okey, but why `console.log(this.prop.some(el => el === undefined), this.prop.indexOf(undefined));` is `false, -1` if `this.prop` is `[undefined]`?

Comment: Nope it doesn't print that, It' prints `true 0` - http://jsbin.com/joxedugeqi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @BelminBedak truth! I am sorry, I am closer to solve my problem now, because I do `data: {arr: new Array(n)}` and I thought that I have an array of `n` `undefined`

Comment: @rel1x [No, as "this implies an array of arrayLength empty slots, not slots with actual undefined values"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray).